# What is meaning of $f(U)$ is open? $f$: function $U : domain$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I want to understand what is the meaning of function $f(U)$ is open.

The textbook states Since $f(U)$ is open, thus for any point $z$ of $f(U)$, 
\begin{align}
|z| > |f(P)|
\end{align}
for $P \in U$.

But i don't know how it is true.

what i know about open is If $f(U)$ is open and for $z \in f(U)$, there is a disc $D(z, \epsilon) \subseteq f(U)$ $i.e$, open set contains some disk.

---

This question comes from Proving "The open mapping theorem" in Complex analyisis.

If $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a non-constant holomorphic function on a connected open set $U$, then $f(U)$ is an open set in $\mathbb{C}$.

and similar argument was used in proving Schwarz lemma

The main textbook i follow is chapter 5 in Robert E Green, Steven G.Krantz, Function theory of one complex variable 3rd.

Comment: What are $U$ and $f$? just some general function?

Comment: @phy-math: more context please !

Comment: What's written doesn't make sense: If $z = f(P)$ for some $P$ in $U$, then $z \in f(U)$, but "$|z| > |f(P)|$" is false. In case it matters, there's a distinction between "$f(U)$ is open" (which refers to an _open set_) and "$f$ is open" (which refers to an _open mapping_, i.e., the condition "$f(U)$ is open for every open set $U$"). Could you please clarify the wording?

Comment: @Andrew D.Wang,Fred,user160738 Sorry for the late response and ambiguous description, The textbook says to show $f(U)$ is open for holomorphic funtion on open set, it is enough to show for given $Q \in f(U)$ there is a disc $D(Q,\epsilon) \subseteq f(U)$.

Comment: I prefer the notation $f[U] = \{f(x): x \in U \}$, the range of $f$ restricted to $U$.

Answer (score 1):

$U$ is a set, and $f$ is a function. I think your confusion stems from thinking $f(U)$ is just another way to refer to the function $f$. But that's not what $f(U)$ means.

$f(U)$ is the *set* of all outputs you could get from applying $f$ to an input from the set $U$. In other words, $f(U)$ is the range of $f$. And the adjective "open" can apply to $f(U)$ just like any *set* could be open using the topology of the ambient space.